# .Net SSL server library

Tags: .net, ssl

I have created a server application that accepts connections over SSL. It's simple and works well enough. However, I'm wondering if there's a library out there that already does that. Ideally, it would be as easy to use as: authenticate with this certificate, listen on this port, and let me know when there's a new client connected. The library would handle threading, connections, disconnections, etc., whereas the application would handle the data exchange. A Google search didn't show me anything, so I don't know if something like that exists.

I have used Apache FTP (Java), so that's kinda what I have in mind. The biggest difference (other than JVM vs .Net) is that this application isn't FTP (or HTTP or any other standard protocol).

Does anybody know if something like this already exists or if I should continue using what I already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to look at [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

It's pretty extensible in how you can configure it to communicate the way you want it to.

Implementing [SSL With WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx).

[SSL Example with Self Hosted Service.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFSSL.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm reading the articles and familiarizing myself with it, since I've never done WCF before. I would've preferred something less MS specific (i.e., what if I wanted to use Mono?), but I'll look into it nonetheless and report back with my findings. Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like you can use WCF in Mono.  I don't know the specifics though as how to get it all to work.  http://www.mono-project.com/WCF

Comment: I think WCF could do the trick, but at the same time, I'm not entirely convinced. It might be lack of knowledge, training, or guidance, so I'll accept the answer nonetheless.
Thanks again.